# Set value of temporary std::future

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, future

I have a function which returns a `std::pair<std::future<bool>,std::future_status>`. In some cases I want future.get() to always return true and I was wondering if there was a legit way of doing it. Currently I am doing something horrendous:

```
std::future<bool> tmp = std::async(std::launch::async,[]()->bool{return true;}); 
return std::make_pair(std::move(tmp), std::future_status::ready);
```

Does anybody know a better way of setting the value of tmp to true?

Comment: ```
std::promise<bool> tmpPromise; //default construct promise
std::future<bool> tmp = tmpPromise.get_future(); //get future associated with promise
tmpPromise.set_value(true); //set future value
```
Is actually a good answer (whoever posted it and then deleted it.). It's synchronous and possibly less resource heavy.

Comment: I posted it. I kept getting an error when executing it on my computer. I wanted to debug it before I left a definitive answer.

Comment: I compiled it and it works on my machine. Will have to test it on the server but I think it should be platform independent.

Comment: I'll undelete the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what effect you're trying to achieve, but you can use a `std::promise` to directly set the value of a `std::future`:

```
#include<future>

std::promise<bool> tmpPromise; //default construct promise

std::future<bool> tmp = tmpPromise.get_future(); //get future associated with promise

tmpPromise.set_value(true); //set future value

return std::make_pair(tmp, std::future_status::ready);
```